# displaying an image in flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, blazeds

I worked with Haxe and actionscript programming, but I'm new to flex. Here's my question. If I want to get image from server (blazeds) in AS3 I'll load it to `Loader` a loader and then add it to some e.g. `MovieClip`. Should I do the same to load an image in flex? Or there some common for flex schema for doing that?

Another question is. If I have an Image on blazeds server what will a better way to get it: to pass it through java (i.e. read it, and then pass to client) or directcly with `Loader`?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BlazeDS is normally used to send objects serialized in AMF. It looks like an overkill to do this for an image, as it will be sent as `ByteArray`, but you'll spend resources processing it. Possibly, a better way, especially if the image is a static content, just serve it as a static file with whatever server running BlazeDS.

There are different ways you can use an image in Flex. Some particular to Flex framework are: use it as a source to the `Image` component, however, this component is somewhat too big for a number of tasks. For example, creating tiles of the same image will be very ineffective if you use this component. There is `BitmapImage`, which is meant to be a lightweight counterpart of `Image`, but it may not have all the desired functionality (it doesn't inherit from `InteractiveObject`, so it cannot respond to mouse events. It is also only available as Spark component.

What I usually do, if I need to use images is this:

1. If I need to cache them in the program (to reuse their `BitmapData`) I write a class that is responsible for loading and caching the results.
2. I write a very simple component that extends `UIComponent` and uses it's `graphics` property to draw the given `BitmapData` into it. This usually allows for simple sharing of the same `BitmapData` in several components.
3. Have this component override `updateDisplayList` method so that it would scale or trim the `BitmapData` it uses.

I do use `Loader` to load images, as there's really no other way to do it. Other components such as `Image` or `SWFLoader` or `BitmapImage` use Loader too and they don't add anything of value on top of that.

Possibly, if you need slice-9-grid functionality, then there is something built-in in the Spark set of components, yet I'd still rather do it myself then rely on it. Flex components aren't to be trusted really.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessary. Setting the `source` property of a `spark.components.Image` object will load the image.

For loading swf files, you can use `mx.controls.SWFLoader` in the same way.

Comment: Thank you! and what is more frequently used `Image` or `Loader`?

Comment: `Image` is a lightweight version with no hassles. Behind the scenes, `Image` uses a `Loader`, but the programmer doesn't need to worry about that if you just want to display an image